# This map is an isometry (in the Riemannian sense) of the hyperbolic plane. Why is the following a proof of it?

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm making my way through a textbook on elementary undergraduate geometry. The author has defined the notion of an isometry between two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with a Riemannian metric. It is a diffeomorphism $\phi:\tilde{V} \to V$ such that for all $P \in \tilde{V}$ and all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $\langle x, y \rangle^{^\sim} _P = \langle (d\phi)_P(x), (d\phi)_P(y) \rangle _{\phi (P)}$.

In a subsequent chapter we encounter the upper half-plane model for the hyperbolic plane, which is the set $H = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | y > 0\}$ equipped with the Riemannian metric $(dx^2 + dy^2)/y^2$. Identifying $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ in the usual way the metric becomes $|dz|^2/Im(z)^2$.

We then go on to consider the map $w:H\to H$ where $w(z) = -1/z$. The author shows that $|dw|^2/Im(w)^2 = |dz|^2/Im(z)^2$ and states that this shows that $w$ is an isometry. He's not explicitly defined an isometry of $H$, so I assume he means in the sense defined above, but it's not clear to me why $|dw|^2/Im(w)^2 = |dz|^2/Im(z)^2$ implies that $w$ is an isometry in that sense.

I have been able to explicitly show that $w$ *is* an isometry in the above sense, but I assume that there's a way to do it using $|dw|^2/Im(w)^2 = |dz|^2/Im(z)^2$. My question is why does $|dw|^2/Im(w)^2 = |dz|^2/Im(z)^2$ imply that $w$ is an isometry as defined above?

Comment: The condition is essentially that the map is infinitesimally an isometry (it preserves the length of tangent vectors), and the fact being used is that a diffeomorphism which is infinitesimally an isometry is globally an isometry ("diffeomorphism" is essential here, as the covering of a circle by a line shows). Maybe you should clarify which part(s) is/are unclear to you ("infinitesimal isometry" or "implies global isometry").

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I understand that $\langle x, y \rangle^{^\sim} _P = \langle (d\phi)_P(x), (d\phi)_P(y) \rangle _{\phi (P)}$ is saying that the map is infinitessimally an isometry. Earlier in the book I have seen that a diffeomorphism satisfying this property (infinitesimal isometry) preserves the lengths of curves, hence is a global isometry.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I guess I can see that what the author has proved is that the map is an infinitesimal isometry. So I think that's helped, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more a matter of notation.

Take $z\in H$ and $x,y\in\mathbb R^2$. Then
$$
\langle d_zw\, x,d_zw \,y\rangle_{w(z)}=:\frac{|dw|^2}{Im(w)^2}(x,y)=\frac{|dz|^2}{Im(z)^2}(x,y):=\langle x,y\rangle_z.
$$

**Added:**

More explicitly, write $z=z_1+iz_2$, $x=(x_1,x_2)\equiv x_1+ix_2$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)\equiv y_1+iy_2$. Then, by definition,
$$
\langle x,y\rangle_z:=\frac{|dz|^2}{Im(z)^2}(x,y)=\frac{x_1y_1+x_2y_2}{z_2^2}.
$$
Now take $w(z)=-1/z=w_1+iw_2$ and define
$$
x'=d_zw\,x=\frac{x_1+ix_2}{z^2}\equiv x_1'+ix_2', \quad y'=d_zw\,y=\frac{y_1+iy_2}{z^2}\equiv y_1'+iy_2'.
$$
Then
$$
\langle d_zw\, x,d_zw \,y\rangle_{w(z)}=\frac{x_1'y_1'+x_2'y_2'}{w_2^2}=:\frac{|dw|^2}{Im(w)^2}(x,y).
$$
Really, their notation is not the best.

Comment: Why is $\langle d_zw\, x,d_zw \,y\rangle_{w(z)}=\frac{|dw|^2}{Im(w)^2}(x,y)$ true? Your use of $=:$ suggests that's by definition? Isn't $\frac{|dw|^2}{Im(w)^2}(x,y)$ equal to $\langle  x,y\rangle_{w(z)}$ by definition?

Comment: Yes, it's by definition what I wrote. But that's why I also wrote that it is more a matter of notation. Usually you write it in terms of the length and than it becomes more transparent (in my opinion). In other words, the derivative of the map $w$ acts on the leaf of the (unit) tangent bundle at $z$, and thus why we *need* to take $d_zw \,x$, etc, while $w$ acts on the upper half plane. So, we do act on the unit tangent bundle.

Comment: I haven't encountered leafs or tangent bundles before, is there a more elementary way to explain what you mean?

Comment: Sure, just added some details to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I think that all makes sense. Just to be clear,
$$
|dw|^2(x,y) = x_1'y_1'+x_2'y_2'
$$
because
$$
|dw|^2 = dw_1^2 + dw_2^2
$$
and $dw_1$ acts as the real part of $x \mapsto x'$, and $dw_2$ acts as the imaginary part of that map?

Comment: Precisely . :-)